# Running two containers in a kubernetes job each with their own initContainers

Tags: kubernetes, yaml

In this SO article I understand that I can run a sequence of `initContainers` before running the containers defined in `spec.template.spec.containers`.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40713573/how-to-run-containers-sequentially-as-a-kubernetes-job

I have two independent containers, each of which requires a sequence of `initContainers` to run in series prior to the container running.

Is it possible to run both sequences of `initContainers` at the same time? Something like this:

```
apiVersion: batch/v1
kind: Job
metadata:
  name: my-test-job
spec:
  backoffLimit: 0
  template:
    spec:
      initContainers:
      - name: init1
        image: busybox
        command: ["echo", "Init 1 Ran!"]
      containers:
      - name: task1
        image: busybox
        imagePullPolicy: Always
        command: ["echo", "Task 1 Ran!"]
      restartPolicy: Never

    spec:
      initContainers:
      - name: init2
        image: busybox
        command: ["echo", "Init 2 Ran!"]
      containers:
      - name: task2
        image: busybox
        imagePullPolicy: Always
        command: ["echo", "Task 2 Ran!"]
      restartPolicy: Never
```

It's not valid to duplicate `spec` as I did in that example of what I'm attempting to achieve. But it demonstrates the sequence of events I want. Initially `init1` and `init2` kick off, and once each finishes, `task1` and `task2` start following their respective init containers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you are describing is best achieved by either using two jobs or let task 1 also be an init Container as they run in sequence.
Alternatively you could use Argo Workflows. 
https://github.com/argoproj/argo